# Description and sitelinks below website name in search results

Tags: html, meta-tags

How can I add "metadata" (green and red lines on the picture below) to a website? Probably the name metadata isn't correct, sorry for that.
I already tried modifying the following tag in the index.html page, but am not sure if this is the right way of doing it:

```
<meta name="description" content="some content...">
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, there are at least two tags which allow you to control how your website appears in search results.

The first one is the **title tag** of your page. This title will of course appear in your browser tab, but it will also appear in the search results. Make sure to use an accurate title which reflects the content of your page. The `<title>` tags should be placed inside de `<head>` tags of your HTML code.

The second one is the **meta description tag**, which will show the user a short description of the content. This is the part marked with a *green line* in your question. The `<meta>` tag also goes in the head tags of your HTML code, usually just after the `<title>` tag.

Example of the mentioned tags with correct syntax:

```
<head>
  <title>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A public platform building the definitive collection of coding questions & answers..."/>
</head>
```

The part marked with a *red line* in your question, is what we call **sitelinks**. They are generated automatically and depend of your website's navigation, the titles and headers you used, etc. This may sound obvious, but you should use different titles and descriptions for each individual page.

The way sitelinks are generated and how you can improve them is very well explained on [Google's page about sitelinks](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/sitelinks).